# Mongoose query to check for specific value in array of searched element

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have s schema like:

```
var EntitySchema = new Schema({
  name : {type: String, default: null},
  organizations : [{
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Organization'
    }}]
});
```

I have an id of organization, How can I make a query for Entity.find({}) and find Entity that has this id in its organizations array?

I used this in mongo shell

```
db.entity.find({"organizations.id": { $in: [ObjectId("ididididididid")]}}).pretty()
```

and it worked, but it doesn't work in express method, do I do something wrong? Does $in works both ways? I have a feeling that its not what I should be using in this query.

Comment: What your data looks like? `organization: [ { id: ObjectId('hashedvalue44') } ]`

Comment: `organizations: [{id: 'hashedvalue44'}, {id: 'hashedvalue55'}]`, or `organizations: ['hashedvalue44', 'hashedvalue55']` either is acceptable as of now.

Answer (score 1):

As per mongo documentation, you can query as below

```
db.entity.find({ "organizations" : { $elemMatch: { "id" : ObjectId("ididididididid") } }}).pretty();
```

Ref: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/